# Change Stackpane#enabled property of one view from another view in JavaFX

Tags: java, class, javafx, controller, fxml

I have 2 FXML files, with 2 seperate FXMLControllers. They are at the same package.

I want to change a stackpane enable property at the first window(first_controller.java) if I click a button at the second window. Which is the easiest solution?

(I tried to merge the controller documents, and I told both of the 2 fxml to use the same controller, to do in an easy way, but did not work. Maybe the controller.java can use only 1 source of FXML?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beg you please don't just use the static way just because of easiness!
Theres a normal solution for your problem.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("Example.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
YourController controller1 = loader.getController();
controllerOfSecondFXML.methodToPassYourController(controller1);
```

So if you split up the loading of the FXML you can get the controllers of your FXMLs easily and use their methods. Just get the controller like i wrote above and pass it to the other one. That's the Object-oriented way.

Comment: Thanks Juce, I appreciate your warning and I'll use it in the future! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the solution.

In the first FXMLController the StackPane must be used as a "public static Stackpane". In this case the other FXML's controller can use this, and change the value of the real instance.